# What is the scope of this circuit?

Tags: adc, dc

I was looking at a schematic block, for an VIn for an ADC and I saw this :

[image]

What is the possible scope for this block?

Comment: I think you will need to write a lot more. I've no idea whatsoever about what you want to know, here. I'm completely clueless. Can you re-phase your question?

Comment: what i need to rephrase ? It's a schematic block with a function from a VIN DC current. It's not a divider , what other information do you need?

Comment: You've selected an answer. So that's that for now. Best wishes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such, the block is rather useless, if the signal source is an ideal voltage supply like in your simulator.

Maybe the analog input is disconnectable or the signal source is simply a resistor to some supply, like NTC temperature sensor. So the 10k pull-down is necessary.

Maybe there is a high impedance signal source, so the capacitor is required for the ADC to sample it properly without voltage sagging.

Maybe there are long wires and the capacitor and the 100 ohm series resitor is to protect from ESD.

Maybe someone just draw the circuit like that because someone else had also drawn the cicuit like that without knowing why they should draw it like that. It's called cargo-culting.

Comment: correct, checking an optional block before this input, there is a floating disconnectable signal source.